# Selenium with java script

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I tried to write the dynamic output of the sum of two numbers in an excel sheet, only the last row is written in excel.

I am not sure if the excel sheet is closed without autosave and opened again for next input.

I would like to know, save or autosave javascript for me to use in selenium parameterization with displaying dynamic values I excel.

Code below:

```
package addegexcelwrite1valuesfl;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class addegexcelwrite1valuesfladd {

    public int add(int a,int b,int u) {
        int c=a+b;
        int p;

        try {
            File src=new File("Filepath");
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
            XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook();

            XSSFSheet sh11= wb.createSheet();
            XSSFRow row=sh11.getRow(u);

            sh11.createRow(u).createCell(0).setCellValue(c);
            FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("Filepath");

            wb.write(fout);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return c;
    }

}
```

`a`, `b` are the input to add numbers, `u` is the row number of the excel from which I am trying to read and pass inputs `a`, `b`. When I am passing first parameter eg a=1,b=2, c is stored in (0,0) the cell but the next time when the loop runs with next input for `a`, `b`, the previous value in cell (0,0) disappears, likewise only my last cell value is appearing.

Comment: Do you think you could post examples of your code? With that, someone might be able to point out the mistake and help you fix it.

Comment: Thank you @Alpha,now have posted the code in the expected format here.a,b are the input to add numbers,u is the rownumber of the excel from which am trying to read and pass inputs a,b .When I am passing first parameter eg a=1,b=2, c is stored in (0,0) th cell but the next time when the loop runs with next input for a,b ,the previous value in cell(0,0) disappears,likewise only my last cell value is appearing .

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be the usage of `sh11.createRow(u)`. Look at what the [documentation for this function](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#createRow-int-) says (emphasis mine):

> Create a new row within the sheet and return the high level representation Note: **If a row already exists at this position, it is removed/overwritten and any existing cell is removed!**

So, instead of creating row `u`, you might want to get the last row and then create row last + 1:

```
int lastRowNumber = sh11.getLastRowNum();
sh11.createRow(lastRowNumber + 1).createCell(0).setCellValue(c);
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,will try doing this way @Alpha